# Determine all local maximas and minimas

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The function is: $f(x,y)=x^2y^2, (x,y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$

$\partial_xf(x,y)=2xy^2$

$\partial_yf(x,y)=2x^2y$

$\partial_{xx}f(x,y)=2y^2$

$\partial_{yy}f(x,y)=2x^2$

$\partial_{xy}f(x,y)=4xy$

so we now that

$2xy^2=0$ and the solution of this equation is that $x = 0$ and $y$ is arbitrary

$2yx^2=0$ and the solution of this equation is that $x$ is arbitrary and $y = 0$

and we get that:

$D^2f(x,0) =\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 \\
0 & 2x^2 
\end{pmatrix}$ which is positive semidefinit

$D^2f(0,y) =\begin{pmatrix}
2y^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ which is positive semidefinit

What can I say at this point of the Hessian matrix? Or how can I find the extrema of the function?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: If there is a minimum, then the Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite, but the converse does not hold. Hence, you have to see that the minima are necessarily among the points of the form $(0,y)$ and $(x,0)$, but in order to check that they are actually minima you need to get a little bit creative. You can look at the value of the function at that points and try to argue that they are smaller than the other points on their neighborhood by other means.

Comment: Can u be maybe a little bit more detailed? I'm still struggling with this problem

Comment: First notice that since the function is the square of $xy$ it is always non-negative. What is the value of $f$ at $(0,y)$ and $(x,0)$?

Comment: I have found out by using a software that the function has a global minimum at point $(0,0)$ but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(x,y)$ is always positive because it is the square of a number -- unless one of $x$ or $y$ is equal to zero.  Therefore, the global minimum is at $f = 0$.  Because the function is smooth, any local max or min must occur when both $f_x = 0$ and $f_y = 0$.  Again, this only happens when one of $x$ or $y$ is zero.  But we already found this to be the global minimum.  Hence, the function has uncountable global minima, which are the lines $x = 0$ and $y = 0$.  The global minima are equivalent to local minima for this function because they all occur at critical points.